# Should I dispose my pages instead of waiting for GC Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows 10 UWP app where I do alot of navigation using

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(myClass));
```

I know that this creates a new instance of the class, myClass in this case, when I navigate. This is all working just fine and I am okay with it.

I do also know that I can set navigation cache, particularly when you are going to use the back stack to navigate. However, I am not doing any of that. I basically have a button to go forward and a button to go back. When the button is clicked, I just call Frame.Navigate as I show above.

The reason I do this, I don't want to have to worry about the navigation stack when I want to go forward and back with this simple navigation.

That said, here is the question. I know that the GC can take time to dispose of the instance of the class. If I navigate quickly from class to class, is it possible that GC did not dispose yet and I am instantiating multiple instances of the class? If so, should I explicitly dispose of the class somehow? I am thinking if I override the OnNavigatedFrom and dispose in there?

So, for example, let's say the following is called quickly (within a second or so) because the user is hitting the buttons to go back and forth.

```
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(myClass));
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(myClass2));
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(myClass));
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(myClass2));
```

Is it possible to end up with two instances of each class temporarily until GC gets around to cleaning up? How should I keep this all clean?

Thanks!

Comment: You say "I know that the GC can take time to dispose of the instance of the class" - That's **wrong** as the GC **never** disposes any class. The GC **may** call a finalizer which **may** call `.Dispose()`, but you would need to know for sure that there is a finalizer that does that and you'd need to know if the finalizer even gets run.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected. But nonetheless, you helped prove my point and in fact, made it even more of a concern because you say it MAY call a finalizer which MAY call dispose. This leaves even more doubt that my old classes or pages, are getting disposed and certainly not in a timely manner or even at all. So, the question still remains, shall I get in the habit of disposing myself? Suggestions on best way to do so?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. You should always explicitly dispose of every `IDisposable` object that you create. That should absolutely become a habit.

Comment: Unless you have unmanaged resources which must be explicitly freed, I don't see why you should take memory management into your own hands like this, that's the GC's job. As long as you don't hold references to objects that you no longer need, you should be good.